# The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_ssis_getfolder', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'

Tags: sql-server-2008

folks.
I'm trying to use the copy wizard to copy my SQL SERVER 2008 database from my Windows 7 Professional 32 bit Acer laptop to my SQL SERVER 2008 Windows 7 home premium 64 bit Samsung Laptop.
The error is:
While trying to find a folder on SQL an OLE DB error was encountered with error code 0x80040E09 (The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_ssis_getfolder', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.).

The question has been answered:
You could GRANT EXECUTE ON MSDB.DBO.sp_ssis_getfolder to [proxy]

Or you could try adding that user to one of the dts/ssis operator/executor roles - starting with user, then operator, then admin to see what level it needs - or read the documentation.

db_ssisadmin db_ssisoperator db_ssisltduser

See the section under msdb here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

Please forgive me.  I took the courses in 2010.  I'm working on a volunteer project. I understand what this answer wants me to do, but I don't know how or where to do it.

The following answer was great, but when I right click on the stored procedure, I don't get "properties" to select.

Check to make sure the user trying to run the stored proc has execute permissions, you can do this in SQL Server Management Studio by going to the Database -> Programmability -> and Right Click on the Stored Proc and select 'Properites', then go to the 'Permissions' section and see if your user is there, if its not, you can add the user and give it EXECUTE permissions, or you can do the following in a new query:
GRANT EXECUTE TO  ON

I am connecting with logins that are owners on both databases.  I am assuming that the execute permission is going to be on the destination server, the msdb database. I am working on the destination (Samsung) laptop connecting to the source database on the Acer, right clicking on the source database and selecting "tasks", copy database.  Things work fine until the Wizard gets to CREATE and then it fails with the error.

I hope somebody can help me with this.  I've been trying to get this working for about a week and am frustrated.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 2):

Open Internet Information Services Manager
Check what Application Pool your IIS Website is using
Go to Application Pools
See what Identity your App Pool is running under

Open SQL Server Management Studio
Connect to your SQL Server instance
Open a New Query for your database
Run this SCRIPT:

```
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE, UPDATE, INSERT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO
[NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]
```

*Replace `[NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]` with whatever Identity your App Pool is running as.

Go back to IIS Manager
Recycle your App Pool
Browse to your website